# Gimp - Make all Cars Yellow

Tags: color, gimp

Let's say that I have a picture of 4 different colored cars.  Black, White, Green, and light blue.  I want to make all of these the same shade of yellow.  If you ignore black I can use Colors, Hue-Saturation to change the color, but getting it to the yellow I want is trial and error.  Getting the next car to be the same yellow would be harder.  Colors, Map, Color Exchange allows me to pick the destination color, but it is still trial and error.  I may get one car to look the correct yellow, but the other one won't.  I have also tried all of the modes.  The black car seems to be a bigger problem.

Is there a way to select the green part of the car and change it to a yellow that I picked up with the dropper (or specify is some other way)?  I then want to do the same to the light blue car and have it be the same yellow.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you are facing "accumulative" problems, is because you are not masking the cars individually or using layers.

But if what you mean is that some colors are harder to transform than others, yes. In a black car, you have less information on the shades, on the shadows. So it might be impossible to do a decent job on some zones of the car. A White car could not have enough differentiation of shades on the reflections for example. Both are unsaturated colors. Saturated ones are easier to change hue.

Answer (score 2):

Lighting, shadows and reflection create a range of colors from the initial paint color. And AFAIK the only tool that maps a range of colors to another is `Colors > Map > Rotate colors`. But it deals only with the hue, you have to deal with the saturation in a separate step.

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]